# Want to centralize code for calling my Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

In my MVC app, I make a lot of Web API calls that require a few lines of code. I'd like to create a centralized method for making API calls and just pass some simple parameters into it e.g. call type (GET, POST, etc), the Url, etc.

Where I need help is that in each scenario, I will return a different object type e.g. Employee, List<Project>, etc. How do I return different object types?

The other issue is that if I want to make a POST or PUT call, I will pass different types of objects into my centralized API call method. Again, I have the same issue, where I have to be able to accept different object types.

I guess, I can just pass Json objects in and out but I'm not sure if that's the right approach or there's a better approach out there. I'm sure others have tried to centralize their Web API call code.

*** UPDATE ***
Here's what I have so far but I need a bit more help. How do I return the result?

```
public static async Task<object> GetApiCall(string apiActionUrl)
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myApiBaseUrl");
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiActionUrl);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
         var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can show 2 samples from the code that you want to centralize? You maybe can create a base class for your code,  or create call handler class,  but in both cases you have to generics for passing parameters and the return types.

Comment: Just updated my original post with a sample code that I've come up with. I've never returned a generic object before so I'm trying to understand how I do that. The other part that I'm not clear about in my code is when I get an error response from my Web API. Then what would I return?

Comment: great, let me write you some code and will publish it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : this is a starting point, you can build on this, but the idea is ApiCaller is a class that implements an interface IApiCaller (so you can mock it later), and this class starts the HttpClient with the same options/headers, and the method will use/dispose this HttpClient to connect to the server, and each method defines the return type T when the caller calls the method (like Get).

```
public interface IApiCaller
{
    Task<T> Get<T>(string apiActionUrl);
}

public class ApiCaller : IApiCaller
{
    private const string ApiBaseUrl = "http://myApiBaseUrl";

    public async Task<T> Get<T>(string apiActionUrl)
    {
        using (var client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(apiActionUrl);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    private static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiBaseUrl),
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return client;
    }
}
```

you can use this class like this:

```
public class SomeMvcController : Controller
{
    private readonly IApiCaller _apiCaller;

    // use this if you don't want to rely on Dependency Injection, OR
    // if you don't use Ioc container for now.     
    public SomeClass(): this(new ApiCaller())
    {
    }

    public SomeClass(IApiCaller apiCaller)
    {
        _apiCaller = apiCaller;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStringFromWebApi()
    {
        string result = await _apiCaller.Get<string>("myApiUrl");

        return result;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This code looks nice and elaborate but there are things about it that are above my level. Would you be kind enough to help me understand it? First, I was not able to call it from my MVC action method where I need to make an API call. I tried MyApp.ApiCaller.Get() but all intellisense gives me is Equals and ReferenceEquals. I don't see the Get method. I'm also not clear why you're inheriting from IApiCaller interface. What is the advantage of it?

Comment: 1- Previously your GetApiCaller method was a static method, but I've changed that to be an instance method, which means you have to initialize ApiCaller class by new it. 2- I used the Interface IApiCaller so you can mock this class for unit testing, google "Moq Library" or "C# unit testing" to know more about unit testing. 3- Your MVC controller will get IApiCaller interface injected to it, which you can use an IoC container like Autofac to setup the dependencies.   Is this clear enough or you need more ?

Comment: I'm somewhat clear but I don't want to take too much of your time. You've been super helpful! I do want to ask one more question if you don't mind though. Isn't better to make it a static class so that I don't have to create a new instance of the ApiCaller class everytime I need to make an API call?

Comment: No worries, things will make sense to you when you start using the code ;) and build on top of it. and if my code was helpful, tick your question as helpful/answered for the sake of other people looking for same scenario.

Comment: I've added an empty constructor to the code above if you don't want to depend on an Ioc container to initialize the ApiCaller class for you, let me know if things are still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Either return a object or use dynamic return type.

Comment: I could use a bit more help. How do I return the "result". Also, what if I get an error from my Web API call, what do I return then?